# Migrate module showing error messages

Tags: migrations

I am importing database from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 with migrate module.

The progress bar is 5%.
The importing data taking a long time.

How could I make it faster? Using Drush?
And the error messages below are having problem?

> Processed 263 (0 created, 0 updated, 263 failed, 0 ignored) in 27.8
>   sec (568/min) - continuing with '1cf4f3dbbFile'
>
> Processed 260 (0 created, 0 updated, 260 failed, 0 ignored) in 27.3
>   sec (571/min) - continuing with '1cf4f3dbbFile'
>
> Processed 258 (0 created, 0 updated, 258 failed, 0 ignored) in 27.5
>   sec (564/min) - continuing with '1cf4f3dbbFile'
>
> Processed 253 (0 created, 0 updated, 253 failed, 0 ignored) in 27.5
>   sec (552/min) - continuing with '1cf4f3dbbFile'

Comment: Drush would be better option even migrate module recommend to use drupal for migration process. This [drush migrate](https://www.drupal.org/node/1806824) would be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone thorugh drupal migration many times and it takes much time if DB is heavy.So Take a breath and keep it going.....once 100% migration is done then you proceed.
And also D2D module provides option to select which content types you want to migrate first.In this way you can divide your migration into parts and process will be fast then previous.
Good Luck :)